# UISearchController attributes of the searchBar view, how to remove the black border lines?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

In use UISearchController, try to modify the searchBar barTintColor attributes, change color.Results presented two black line, the effect such as the following picture.

[image]

how can I remove the two black line?

my code:

```
// 搜索结果控制器
searchVC = SearchViewController()

searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchVC)
// 设置UISearchController属性
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = true
// 设置UISearchBar属性
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit() //直接关系到searchBar会不会上推
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = BackgroudGray
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.yellowColor()

// 设置本ViewController
definesPresentationContext = true

tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

Comment: maybe try setting the background image of the search bar to a blank UIIMage, like searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()

Comment: Set the backgroundImage properties can remove the black line, thank you very much!However, when I click the SearchBar, its color immediately back to the default color and move to the location of the navigation bar.I want the color of the SearchBar don't change after the click.How to do?

Comment: I know how to deal with, thank you.Use this method:`searchController.searchBar.setBackgroundImage(Configure.createImageWithColor(SearchBarGray), forBarPosition: .Any, barMetrics: .Default)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one

searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = UIImage()
searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

Comment: @RED Thank you for your help, I have solved this problem. My solution is similar to your approach.
Create a UIImage instance with UIColor and assign it to the backgroundImage property.